# Using HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync(), how to handle HttpRequestException based on HttpStatusCode without extra SendAsync calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

`System.Net.Http.Json`'s `HttpClient` extension methods such as `GetFromJsonAsync()` greatly simplifies the routine codes to retrieve json objects from a web API. It's a pleasure to use.

But because of the way it's designed (returning deserialized objects directly), it does not produce any `HttpResponseMessage` for inspection that allows me to take custom actions based on `HttpStatusCode`.

Instead, non-success status codes results in a `HttpRequestException`, which does not appear to offer any properties that expose strongly typed `HttpStatusCode`. Instead, the status code is included in the exception's `Message` string itself.

**Edit: .NET 5.0 added the `HttpRequestException.StatusCode` property, so it can now be inspected when calling `GetFromJsonAsync`.**

//old post below

So I've been doing something like this:

```
try
{
  var cars = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Car>>("/api/cars");
  //...
}
            
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
   if (ex.Message.Contains(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString()))
   {
     //Show unauthorized error page...
   }
   //...
}
```

This feels a bit hacky. With the old school way of creating `HttpRequestMessage` and calling `SendAsync`, we naturally got the chance to inspect a response's `HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode`. Adding some of those codes back would defeat the convenient purpose of using the one-liners in `System.Net.Http.Json`.

Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found that .GetFromJsonAsync<T> throws exception based on StatusCode: ```System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException 
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()```

Comment: wrt my previous comment, found this approach: `HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync(HttpClientInstance, requestUri, body, cancellationToken);`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use:

```
// return HttpResponseMessage
var res= await httpClient.GetAsync<List<Car>>("/api/cars")

if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   var cars = res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Car>>();
else
   // deal with the HttpResponseMessage directly as you used to
```

I use a base class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MyProject.ClientAPI
{
    public abstract class ClientAPI
    {
        protected readonly HttpClient Http;
        private readonly string BaseRoute;

        protected ClientAPI(string baseRoute, HttpClient http)
        {
            BaseRoute = baseRoute;
            Http = http;
        }

        protected async Task<TReturn> GetAsync<TReturn>(string relativeUri)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = await Http.GetAsync($"{BaseRoute}/{relativeUri}");
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TReturn>();
            }
            else
            {
                string msg = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
        }
        
        protected async Task<TReturn> PostAsync<TReturn, TRequest>(string relativeUri, TRequest request)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<TRequest>($"{BaseRoute}/{relativeUri}", request);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TReturn>();
            }
            else
            {
                string msg = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then from derived class, we're back to the one-liner

```
public class MySpecificAPI : ClientAPI
{
    public MySpecificAPI(HttpClient http) : base("api/myspecificapi", http) {}
    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetMyClassAsync(int ownerId)
    {
        try
        {
            return GetAsync<IEnumerable<MyClass>>($"apiMethodName?ownerId={ownerId}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Deal with exception
        }
    }
    
    // repeat for post
}
```

### UPDATE:  HANDLING NULL RETURNS

Having encountered a valid scenario where the WebAPI returns null, the line:

```
return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TReturn>();
```

will throw a Json Deserialization error.

To address this, we need to detect NoContent response (204) and handle accordingly:

```
if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
    return default(TReturn);
else if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TReturn>();
```

Comment: Actually, I also just found out that .NET 5.0 added the HttpRequestException.StatusCode property. Was using .NET Core 3.1 so I didn't know.

Comment: `GetAsync` does not take a type argument in a .NET 5 Blazor application, so the suggested code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ted ... Note that the GetAsync method called from MySpecificAPI (where I use type) is not the HttpClient.GetAsync, it is the GetAsync method in my base class ClientAPI.  In turn ClientAPI calls the HttpClient.GetAsync method (which does not support type argument).  The above code definitely works or there's some strange magic going on in my application ;-)

Comment: @Ted Good catch on the null handling issue, you saved my day!

Answer (score 18):

I just found out that .NET 5.0 actually added the `StatusCode` Property to the `HttpRequestException` class!

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/32455

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception.statuscode?view=net-5.0