# Why is Blazor authentication library sending access token JWT with empty Payload?

Tags: c#, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, auth0

I am using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication (6.0.15)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/6.0.15) with Auth0 as IdP.

On the Blazor WASM side, I followed the standards instructions:

In my Program.cs:

```
...
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "SecureAPIClient",
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
...
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Auth0", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("profile");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
});
...
```

Then in my component's `OnInilialized` method:

```
...
HttpClient http = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SecureAPIClient");
var response = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<POSTS>(getPostsUrl);
...
```

But the response I get from Kestrel server is:

```
www-authenticate Bearer error="invalid_token"
```

Below is a screenshot of my network tab:
[image]

I can see the access_token from the token request, please see picture below:

[image]

It appears that the access token JWT has an empty payload.

I am struggling to understand why. Any idea ?

### Added, for more clarification

[image]

What could make the JWT added to the request by **BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler** to have and empty payload ?

I mean to look like this: `header..secret`

I get the error below when I try to validate the JWT on jwt.io:

```
Warning: Looks like your JWT payload is not a valid JSON object. JWT payloads must be top level JSON object as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-7.2
```

Comment: You are getting a status of 401.  Most servers when you get an error the body is empty.  You are getting a http header in the response with the toke.  It is not the payload (body). OAuth is 2.0 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0#additional-resources  You have "Auth0"

Comment: The token response is part of the openid connect process, not the actual request body. To put it differently, the JWT sent in the Authorization header of the actual request, is missing the body payload part: JWT = header.payload.secret

Comment: Please see added picture.

Comment: Your error is due to the body being empty which is normal when you do not get a 200 OK.  You are getting a 401 status.   The request token is a GET which means the body is empty.  You are using a POST (means there is a body) which is wrong : http.GetFromJsonAsync<POSTS>(getPostsUrl);

Comment: @jdweng, you still don't get the point. I know the difference between Get and Post requests. Maybe you are confused with POSTS. Here it is just a placeholder to say that the request should return a list of Posts (DTO) from the API, I am not sending a Post request. And I am instead talking about the Payload (Body) of the JWT. The request works well when I remove the [Authorize] attribute from the API endpoint. So the issue is the JWT (token) from the Authorization header is invalid because it seems to be missing the Payload part. I don't understand how this is happening.

Comment: Let concentrate on the error which says "Warning: Looks like your JWT payload is not a valid JSON object. JWT payloads must be top level JSON object as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-7.2".  This make no sense since you do not need a payload (body) if you are just retrieving data.  You request header even says GET.  Why is the server returning errors in the payload when you do not have a payload?  Where are you trying to validate the JWT.  You shouldn't be validating a response if the status code is not 200 OK.  I think that is adding to the confusion.

Comment: The payload here is not the request payload, as you say, this is a GET request, so no payload. If you recall, the JWT format is: HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE. The JWT that Blazor is adding to my request Authorization header, so I can access the secured GET_POSTS endpoint, has the format HEADER..SIGNATURE the PAYLOAD part is missing, that is what I mean by payload. I am wondering was is happening so blazor generate such a broken JWT.

Comment: The error message "Warning: Looks like your JWT..." is coming from https://jwt.io, when I test the generated JWT, not from my web server.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with Auth0 setup, since they are the one to create the id and access tokens

Comment: See following which shows how to handle the null returns : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383186/using-httpclient-getfromjsonasync-how-to-handle-httprequestexception-based-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, it was Auth0 related, I got the right direction from this [link](https://community.auth0.com/t/empty-payload-in-access-token/75952), he was facing the exact same issue.

The solution is to add your audience in your config:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Auth0", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters.Add("audience", "https://your-audience"); // <<== Add this
});
```

And your JWT will have a payload.