# How to use rest API that has different response objects for Success and Error Statuses on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working a rest API that has  2 types of response objects. For instance if status is success, It returning a json object with some fields if is not, it returning just string :) like "ERROR_MESSAGE_HERE". Error response not encapsulate with a class or sth just string.

I want to handle this but, I am using http client that developed by our company. This http client using .NET http client also but, some methods it has. It expecting a response object class from me when i add success object that belongs to API if response is not success it returning  Deserialize exception.

I Know I can use try catch to handle this but I do not prefer firstly. Is there any suggestions about effective ways to handle this responses?

Comment: The question is unclear. All ASP.NET Core applications return different success and error status codes - that's part of HTTP itself. All return different responses for successes, errors and standard-compliant ProblemDetails responses for validation errors. HttpClient easily handles all of them, because it doesn't try to deserialize. That's up to the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync(), how to handle HttpRequestException based on HttpStatusCode without extra SendAsync calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383186/using-httpclient-getfromjsonasync-how-to-handle-httprequestexception-based-on)

Comment: If your Web API returns a 200 response containing an error message, you have a serious bug and every client developer will hate you. Your question is exactly why: they can't tell whether the call worked or not, whether to retry or abort, until they parse the response. Instead of letting eg Polly retry specific cases they'll have to write the code themselves now

Comment: Any API can return different status codes I know it. The problem is they sending a response object if get 200, when we getting 400 or any error API returning just string. Our Success response model does not contation any error message or sth.

Comment: If you get the error content only when the status is 400 what's the problem? If you use `GetAsync` you get back an `HttpResponseMessage` that allows you to check the status code before deserializing the content the way you want. That's what the duplicate shows

Comment: Post your code and examples of success and error responses. It's unclear what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main approaches you can take. Assuming you are using `System.Text.Json` (but the same can be done with Newtonsoft Json.NET):

1. Use one of the [DOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-7-0) options to dynamically process the data. For example via `JsonNode` API - you pass `JsonNode` as type to your HTTP client wrapper and then handle deserialization:

   ```cs
   // var js_str = """{"pr":1}""";
   var js_str = "\"error_here\"";
   var deserialize = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(js_str);
   if (deserialize is JsonValue { } jval)
   {
       var value = jval.GetValue<string>();
   }
   else
   {
       var myClass = deserialize.Deserialize<MyClass>();
   }
   ```
2. Create custom type with [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) which will analyze node type. Something to get you started (can be vastly improved, for example by making it generic and using [factory approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter)):

   ```cs
   [JsonConverter(typeof(ErrorOrDataConverter))]
   class StringOrData
   {
       public string? StringValue { get; set; }
       public MyClass? Data { get; set; }
       public bool IsString { get; set; }
   }

   class ErrorOrDataConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<StringOrData>
   {
       public override StringOrData? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
       {
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
           {
               return new StringOrData
               {
                   StringValue = reader.GetString()!,
                   IsString = true
               };
           }

           return new StringOrData
           {
               Data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(ref reader, options)!
           };
       }

       public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, StringOrData value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

P.S.

I would argue that possibly a better way would be to handle this on the library side somehow, where you can analyze response status to select correct type to deserialize. For example you can add overloads with 2 generic parameters and return something like [`OneOf`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) or `Either`.

Comment: A better option would be to check the HTTP status code for errors and *then* decide how to deserialize. Returning a 200 response containing an error message isn't just a bug. It's evil, actively hostile against client developers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, but based on the description it seems that that is not an option because some wrapper library is used and deserialization happens to the provided type either way.

Answer (score 0):

Using "try catch" is the most practical way.

Comment: I know but we dont prefer it. We have to add some logging business when exception occurs or some logics to handle error and return fluent response to UI's. If we cant find any solution, we have to :)

Comment: It's definitely *not* the most practical way or even needed. You can inspect the response status code before deserializing