# Memory leaking in .NET HttpClient, JsonSerializer or misused Stream?

Tags: c#, httpclient, system.text.json, background-service, jsonserializer

I have a basic background class in an otherwise empty ASP.NET Core 8 Minimal API project.

App startup is just:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SteamAppListDumpService>();
```

The background class is for saving snapshots of a Steam API endpoint, all basic stuff:

```
public class SteamAppListDumpService : BackgroundService
{
    static TimeSpan RepeatDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    private string GetSteamKey() => "...";

    private string GetAppListUrl(int? lastAppId = null)
    {
        return $"https://api.steampowered.com/IStoreService/GetAppList/v1/?key={GetSteamKey()}" +
            (lastAppId.HasValue ? $"&last_appid={lastAppId}" : "");
    }

    public SteamAppListDumpService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await DumpAppList();
            await Task.Delay(RepeatDelay, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public record SteamApiGetAppListApp(int appid, string name, int last_modified, int price_change_number);
    public record SteamApiGetAppListResponse(List<SteamApiGetAppListApp> apps, bool have_more_results, int last_appid);
    public record SteamApiGetAppListOuterResponse(SteamApiGetAppListResponse response);

    protected async Task DumpAppList()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var appList = new List<SteamApiGetAppListApp>();
            int? lastAppId = null;
            do
            {
                using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetAppListUrl(lastAppId));
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new Exception($"API Returned Invalid Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SteamApiGetAppListOuterResponse>(responseString)!.response;
                appList.AddRange(responseObject.apps);
                lastAppId = responseObject.have_more_results ? responseObject.last_appid : null;

            } while (lastAppId != null);

            var contentBytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(appList);
            using var output = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Config.DumpDataPath, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss") + ".json.gz"));
            using var gz = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress);
            gz.Write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("skipped...");
        }
    }
}
```

The API returns approx 16 MB of data in total, then it compresses/saves it to a 4 MB file, every 30 minutes, nothing else. In between runs, when the garbage collector runs I would expect the memory consumption to drop to almost nothing, but it increases over time, as an example it's been running for 2 hours on my PC and is consuming 700MB memory. On my server it's been running for 24 hours and is now consuming 2.5 GB memory.

As far as I can tell all the streams are disposed, `HttpClient` is created using the recommended `IHttpClientFactory`, does anyone know why this basic functionality is consuming so much memory even after garbage collection? I've tried looking at it in the VS manage memory dump but can't find much useful. Does this point to a memory leak in one of the classes (i.e. `HttpClient` / `SerializeToUtf8Bytes`) or am I missing something?

The `responseString` and `contentBytes` are usually around 2MB.

Comment: Garbage Collection only works if there are no links to the object.  c# uses ByRef which adds links instead of creating new objects.  Make sure you have no links to an objects so they get properly disposed.  GC runs in background mode in low priority or when memory is low.  Your memory usage is low around 25% (700MB/2.5GB).  there may be other tasks that are operating at a higher priority so GC doesn't run.

Comment: Any time you allocate a contiguous block of memory >= 85,000 bytes in size, it goes into the [large object heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap).  Unlike the regular heap it isn't compactified unless you do so [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode) so it can grow due to fragmentation giving the appearance of a memory leak.  See [Why Large Object Heap and why do we care?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836).

Comment: So, are either the `responseString` or the `contentBytes` larger than 85,000 bytes?

Comment: Thanks @dbc I'll read into that more, yes, they are indeed larger than 85,000 bytes. The responseString and contentBytes are usually around 2MB.

Comment: @Zak123 - I can't reproduce your problem since I can't call your storage service, but I rewrote your `DumpAppList()` to eliminate the large `responseString` and `contentBytes` objects here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zvHRVy.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you allocate a contiguous block of memory >= 85,000 bytes in size, it goes into the [large object heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap). Unlike the regular heap it isn't compactified unless you do so [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode)<sup>[1]</sup> so it can grow due to fragmentation giving the appearance of a memory leak.  See *[Why Large Object Heap and why do we care?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836)*.

As your `responseString` and `contentBytes` are usually around 2 MB I would recommend rewriting your code to eliminate them.  Instead, asynchronously stream directly from your server and to your JSON file using the relevant built-in APIs like so:

```
const int BufferSize = 16384;
const bool UseAsyncFileStreams = true; //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_Boolean_

protected async Task DumpAppList()
{
    try
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var appList = new List<SteamApiGetAppListApp>();
        int? lastAppId = null;
        do
        {
            // Get the SteamApiGetAppListOuterResponse directly from JSON using HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync() without the intermediate string.
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync
            // If you need customized error handling see 
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383186/using-httpclient-getfromjsonasync-how-to-handle-httprequestexception-based-on
            var responseObject = (await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<SteamApiGetAppListOuterResponse>(GetAppListUrl(lastAppId)))
                !.response;
            appList.AddRange(responseObject.apps);
            lastAppId = responseObject.have_more_results ? responseObject.last_appid : null;

        } while (lastAppId != null);

        await using var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Config.DumpDataPath, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss") + ".json.gz"),
                                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: BufferSize, useAsync: UseAsyncFileStreams);
        await using var gz = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress);
        // See https://faithlife.codes/blog/2012/06/always-wrap-gzipstream-with-bufferedstream/ for a discussion of buffer sizes vs compression ratios.
        await using var buffer = new BufferedStream(gz, BufferSize);
        // Serialize directly to the buffered, compressed output stream without the intermediate in-memory array.
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(buffer, appList);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("skipped...");
    }
}
```

Notes:

- [`GZipStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream) does not buffer its input so there is a chance that streaming to it incrementally can result in worse compression ratios.  However, as discussed by Bradley Grainger in [Always wrap GZipStream with BufferedStream](https://faithlife.codes/blog/2012/06/always-wrap-gzipstream-with-bufferedstream/), buffering the incremental writes using a buffer that is 8K or larger effectively eliminates the problem.
- According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-io-filestream-ctor(system-string-system-io-filemode-system-io-fileaccess-system-io-fileshare-system-int32-system-boolean)), the `useAsync` argument to the `FileStream` constructor

  > Specifies whether to use asynchronous I/O or synchronous I/O. However, note that the underlying operating system might not support asynchronous I/O, so when specifying true, the handle might be opened synchronously depending on the platform. When opened asynchronously, the [BeginRead(Byte[], Int32, Int32, AsyncCallback, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.beginread?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream_BeginRead_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) and [BeginWrite(Byte[], Int32, Int32, AsyncCallback, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.beginwrite?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream_BeginWrite_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) methods perform better on large reads or writes, but they might be much slower for small reads or writes. If the application is designed to take advantage of asynchronous I/O, set the useAsync parameter to true. Using asynchronous I/O correctly can speed up applications by as much as a factor of 10, but using it without redesigning the application for asynchronous I/O can decrease performance by as much as a factor of 10.

  Thus you may need to test to see whether, in practice, you get better performance with `UseAsyncFileStreams` equal to `true` or `false`.  You may also need to play around with the buffer sizes to get the best performance and compression ratio -- always being sure to keep the buffer smaller than 85,000 bytes.
- If you think large object heap fragmentation may be a problem, see the MSFT article [The large object heap on Windows systems: A debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap#a-debugger) for suggestions on how to investigate further.
- Since your `DumpAppList()` method only runs every half hour anyway, you might try compacting the large object heap manually after each run to see if that helps:

  ```
   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
   {
       while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           await DumpAppList();
           GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
           GC.Collect();           

           await Task.Delay(RepeatDelay, stoppingToken);
       }
   }
  ```
- You may want to pass the `CancellationToken stoppingToken` into `DumpAppList()`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Do note that, in [Memory management and garbage collection (GC) in ASP.NET Core: Large object heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-8.0#large-object-heap), MSFT writes:

> In containers using .NET Core 3.0 and later, the LOH is automatically compacted.

So my statement about when LOH compaction occurs may be out of date on certain platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! Using your buffered version made a big difference to memory usage. One other misunderstanding I had was the ServerGarbageCollection mode, I wasn't aware .NET console vs ASP.NET (background service) used a different default garbage collection mode. With your code and the alternative garbage collection method it's now consuming ~100MB after a simulated 24hr run instead of 1.5GB.

Comment: Could do even better by streaming the results of the paging requests, so the list is never stored as one block.

Answer (score 3):

An even better version of [@dbc's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78136783/14868997): you could serialize each page as it comes in, rather than storing the whole list and reserializing it as one.

Use the new `IAsyncEnumerable` interface and `yield return` to allow async streaming of the objects. `JsonSerializer` can serialize that on the fly.

```cs
const int BufferSize = 16384;
const bool UseAsyncFileStreams = true;

private async IAsyncEnumerable<SteamApiGetAppListApp> GetAllApps()
{
    using var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    int? lastAppId = null;
    do
    {
        var responseObject = (await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<SteamApiGetAppListOuterResponse>(GetAppListUrl(lastAppId)))
            ?.response;

        if (responseObject?.apps == null)
            break;

        foreach (var app in responseObject.apps)
        {
            yield return app;
        }
        lastAppId = responseObject.have_more_results ? responseObject.last_appid : null;
    } while (lastAppId != null);
}

protected async Task DumpAppList()
{
    try
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Config.DumpDataPath, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss") + ".json.gz")
        await using var output = new FileStream(
            filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,
            FileShare.None, bufferSize: BufferSize, useAsync: UseAsyncFileStreams);
        await using var gz = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress);
        await using var buffer = new BufferedStream(gz, BufferSize);

        var appList = GetAllApps();

        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(buffer, appList);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("skipped...");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do `var appList = await GetAllApps();` it won't compile.  I think you need to do `var appList = GetAllApps();`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HoKEV2 and https://dotnetfiddle.net/vh6n35.

Comment: Thanks! This is all great info, I'm very out of date with my C# knowledge so it's really interesting to see the more efficient ways to do things like this utilizing the new(ish) language features

Comment: @dbc Quite right, and I also missed the use of `lastAppId` within the loop (thereby needing an initializer)